# Perform DB load test scenario SQL with variables in Jmeter

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, jmeter, load-testing

I would like to perform following Postgresql DB load test.

Time of load test is 150 seconds.

One user makes one request in each 5 seconds up to end of test.

New user start in each second.

Maximum number of users is 150.

Every each request should be different. In detail it is SQL query with two different variables.

Content of SQL query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT url FROM <variable1> WHERE url ILIKE '% <variable2> %'
```

where both variables comes from two different pools of strings generated somehow by me.

What I already know is how to make successful JDBC connection and make graphs I am interested in (Actvie Threads Over Time, Response Time vs Threads, Response Time Over Time).

I was trying to figure out how to solve variable part, but I failed. I was trying to generate them with BeanShell in Java. Also, I was trying to perform this scenario omitting variable part, but I also failed.

Seeking for help,
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables `variable1` and `variable2` you can call it with surrounding `${}`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT url FROM ${variable1} WHERE url ILIKE '% || ${variable2} || %'
```